# How to break down a string inside array into more arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

Basically I have an array with several string as values (not associative array). I need to get particular parts of each string and transform it into an array with two values.

Here's the structure of my array:

```
$data = array(
"A1 -- B1",
"A2 -- B2",
"A3 -- B3",
"A1 -- A2",
"A2 -- A3",
"B2 -- B3",
"B1 -- B3",
);
```

So I need each of these values to become an array like so:

```
$data = array(
    array("A1", "B1");
    array("A2", "B2");
    ...
);
```

I've been thinking about using `preg_split` to break each string down but couldn't get it to work within an array. Not sure `preg_split` is the best way to do it, so I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($data as $k => $c){
    $data[$k] = explode(" -- ", $c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$data = array(
"A1 -- B1",
"A2 -- B2",
"A3 -- B3",
"A1 -- A2",
"A2 -- A3",
"B2 -- B3",
"B1 -- B3",
);

$res             = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
   $res[$key]    = explode(" -- ",$val);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => A2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => A3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => B2
            [1] => B3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => B1
            [1] => B3
        )

)
```

Comment: Why are you using two loops when you only need one, creating unnecessary temp vars, and using trim() when you don't need to? @Wayne Whitty's answer is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Don't look at me. But to answer your question, votes are the community's way of showing which answers are good and which are bad. If you got downvoted it means someone in the community did not think your answer was a good one, possibly for the same reasons I pointed out.

Comment: Ok..I take it in a positive way...I will try to improve the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
"A1 -- B1",
"A2 -- B2",
"A3 -- B3",
"A1 -- A2",
"A2 -- A3",
"B2 -- B3",
"B1 -- B3",
);

$new = array();
foreach($data as $d){
$new[] = split(" -- ", $d);
}

var_dump($new);
```

Gives:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'A1' (length=2)
      1 => string 'B1' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'A2' (length=2)
      1 => string 'B2' (length=2)
 ... etc
```

Comment: `split()` is for when you need a regex, you don't need it for this. You need to just use `explode()`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
    $expArray = explode(' -- ', $value);
    $newArray[] = array($expArray[0], $expArray[1]);
}

$newArray
```

is the final array.

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
$result_array=array();

foreach($data as $val){
    $ex = explode(" -- ", $val);
    array_push($result_array,$ex);
}

print_r($result_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll just join the answers since i had it ready anyway.

I also created a custom foreach loop to iterate through each item in the array, then split that item (if it is a string) into an array.

You could also expend the function i wrote to allow recursion. For example, if not all items in the array are string but if some items are also arrays which contain string, which you want to `explode`, then a recursion is needed.

But i left that out in this exampe:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/xYjXur

---

```
<?php

function splitStringInArrayToArray ( $delimiter = ' -- ', array $array )
{
    foreach ( $array as &$item )
    {
        if ( is_array ( $item ) )
            throw new Exception("oh noes, problem");

        $item = explode ( $delimiter, $item );
    }

    return $array;
}

$data = array(
"A1 -- B1",
"A2 -- B2",
"A3 -- B3",
"A1 -- A2",
"A2 -- A3",
"B2 -- B3",
"B1 -- B3"
);

$new = splitStringInArrayToArray ( ' -- ', $data );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new);
echo '</pre>';
```